# Storing data from Android app in Google

Tags: android

I am writing an android app which provides scores to users based on Questions and answers. I am planning to bundle the app with the questions. I want to store the user's score on some web server. For this I need to implement some kind of an authentication mechanism as well as I need some web based datastorage. Realized that Google App engine can be used for this purpose.

However, I found only one framework for this Google Cloud Messaging (GCM). Looks like this framework has far more use cases than what i originally require. i.e, it also allows to send messaging from cloud to the device. However i am not sure if we can use this to send data from Android to Google Cloud and store it in Google App Engine.

Just wanted to check if there is any framework which *only* exactly what i wanted, ie., to store and retrieve the data rather than acting as a messaging service.

Comment: Search for "Gree" openfeint's new service.

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) is use to send message to all of your app user. Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) is for push notification service. [image]

To store your game scores, better use web service, Like php or ,net or other web service.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a simple Java Servlet on the Google App Engine and send HTTP requests from the Android device with the score data.

On the Android device, you will need to aonfigure Internet access rights and a HTTP client library.

Comment: Yes, that should also do. But i found Google Cloud Storage which solves exactly my purpose without the hassle of writing a Java Servlet. Thank you!!.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I can use [Google Cloud Storage](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/getting-started) which serves my purpose. Haven't explored it yet, but will definitely try it.